# odd datetime difference in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Could someone tell me how come python shows a difference of 1310 seconds between two dates?

```
import datetime
time1=datetime.datetime(2016,12,8,20,5,0)
time2=datetime.datetime(2016,12,7,19,43,10)
timediff=time1-time2
print(timediff)
print(timediff.seconds)

>1 day, 0:21:50
>1310
```

Comment: It's not the `totalseconds`

Comment: Just the "time" part in seconds: 21 mins and 50 secs = 1310. To get 87710, use `timediff.total_seconds()`, as @WillemVanOnsem suggests.

Answer (score 6):

As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) a `timedelta` object has three fields: `days`; `seconds`; and `microseconds`. Or as is specified in the documentation:

> **`class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)`**
>
> (...)
>
> **Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally**. Arguments are converted to those units:
>
> - A millisecond is converted to 1000 microseconds.
> - A minute is converted to 60 seconds.
> - An hour is converted to 3600 seconds.
> - A week is converted to 7 days.

(formatting added)

Althout the constructor is `timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)` and thus provides ways to enter hours, it thus converts the `minutes`, `hours`, etc. all to seconds. The constructor will look like:

```
def __init__(self, days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0):
    self.microseconds = microseconds+1000*milliseconds
    self.seconds = seconds+60*minutes+3600*hours+self.microseconds//1000000
    self.microseconds %= 1000000
    self.days = days+7*weeks+self.seconds//86400
    self.seconds %= 86400
```

(but probably a bit more advanced, etc.)

So that means that `.seconds` actually is modulo day, and without microseconds.

You can however use [`timediff.total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to return the total amount of seconds:

```
>>> timediff.total_seconds()
87710.0
```

So `total_seconds()` is basically:

```
def total_seconds(self):
    return 86400.0*self.days+self.seconds+1e-6*self.microseconds
    #      ^ number of seconds in a day   ^
    #                                     | 1 micro is 1e-6
```

If you divide your `1310` by `60`, you will see that it returns:

```
>>> 1310/60 # obtain number of minutes
21.833333333333332
>>> 1310%60 # obtain number of seconds  (without minutes)
50
```

so 21 minutes and 50 seconds